# Action 'Create data quality schema' finished with errors, aborting installation

Tags: sql-server, installation, components, data-quality-services

During DQS installation, I get the following error message

```
[2015/02/17 01:41:37 PM] Extracting script: DQS_Data.dqs
[2015/02/17 01:41:37 PM] Extracting script: DefaultKbs.xml
[2015/02/17 01:41:37 PM] Total scripts extracted: 25
[2015/02/17 01:41:37 PM] Action 'Load Installation Scripts' finished successfully.
[2015/02/17 01:41:37 PM] Executing action: Create data quality schema.
[2015/02/17 01:41:37 PM] Script: 'recreate_schema.bat RCSL1227 DQS SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
[2015/02/17 01:41:38 PM] 
[2015/02/17 01:41:38 PM] 1 was unexpected at this time.
```

I have tried a few good links like:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce0e9bfa-eb36-40b7-be2a-a24665f018d1/dqs-installer-fails-with-error-script-process-returned-unexpected-exit-code-1?forum=sqldataqualityservices

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case some else pumps into something similar... After 2 days of searching, I realized that that when asked for the admin password, I included the character ")" and it was rejected.

I changed my password to something else and DQS installed successfully.